# How to make vertical text in Angular so that it is part of the page flow?

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to use vertical text in a table cell. However, when I simply use the style `transform: rotate(270deg)`, the cell retains its pre-rotation width and the rotated text is not constrained to the cell.

Is it possible to use Javascript to change the dimensions of the table cell and move the text so the text fits within the cell and the cell has the correct height and width?

Here's a jQuery implementation, but it has trouble with linebreaks and the cells don't always resize or center properly. Calling the fixup multiple times after reflows doesn't work well either.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rotates = $('.fixup .rotate'),
    max = 0;

  function fixRotate() {
    rotates.each(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      var w = $this.width();
      var h = $this.height();
      var $p = $this.parent(".axle");
      var rowHeight = $p.height();
      var cellWidth = $p.width();
      $p.css('min-height', w + 'px');
      $p.css('max-height', Math.max(rowHeight, w) + 'px');
      $p.css('height', Math.max(rowHeight, w) + 'px');
      $p.css('min-width', h + 'px');
      $p.css('width', h + 'px');
      $p.css('max-width', h + 'px');
    });
  }
  fixRotate();
  setTimeout(fixRotate, 2000);
  setTimeout(fixRotate, 4000);
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center
}
.axle {
  position: relative;
}
.rotate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";
  transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
}
.float {
  float: left;
}
.box {
  border: solid 1px grey;
}
.example {
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  min-width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
  Table, plain CSS:
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="axle">
        <div class='rotate'>title</div>
      </td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td class="axle">
        <div class='rotate'>this is a
          <br>three-line
          <br>cell</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="axle">
        <div class='rotate'>longertitle</div>
      </td>
      <td>Great scott
        <br>this is neat</td>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>


  </table>
</div>
<div class="example">
  Table with fixup:

  <table class="fixup">
    <tr>
      <td class="axle">
        <div class='rotate'>title</div>
      </td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td class="axle">
        <div class='rotate'>this is a
          <br>three-line
          <br>cell</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="axle">
        <div class='rotate'>longertitle</div>
      </td>
      <td>Great scott
        <br>this is neat</td>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>


  </table>
</div>
<div class="example">Table with fixup, content variation:

  <table class="fixup">
    <tr>
      <td class="axle">
        <div class='rotate'>title</div>
      </td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td class="axle">
        <div class='rotate'>this is a
          <br>three-line
          <br>cell</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="axle">
        <div class='rotate'>very very long
          <br>title and breaks</div>
      </td>
      <td>Great scott
        <br>this is neat</td>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>


  </table>
</div>

<div class="example">divs, plain css:
  <div>
    <div class="box float axle">
      <div class="rotate">testing</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box float axle">
      <div class="rotate">testing 123</div>
    </div>
    <div>meep meep</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example">divs, fixup:
  <div class=fixup>
    <div class="box float axle">
      <div class="rotate">testing</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box float axle">
      <div class="rotate">testing 123</div>
    </div>
    <div>meep meep</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: normally would explore css solutions first. Without seeing any code to replicate this it's hard to do that. Obvious questions would be what css is currently acting on cells and why it has `pre-rotated` dimensions and not have the transform right from the start

Comment: @charlietfl good point, added example

Comment: what prevents you limiting td width by setting class on td and rule(s) in css?

Comment: @charlietfl I don't understand what you mean, are you referring to setting the max-width on the td elements directly?

Comment: well, this was just some quick code, I don't use jQuery much and it would have taken too much time to figure out how to create the classes and change them etc. Besides, the line height is the important one and it uses the same one on both table rows even though it should vary :-(

Comment: to be honest without a worst case representation and expected results is hard to really know what you need

Comment: Ok, made the examples behave worse.